# Выгрузка редактируемого файла в FileZilla

Tags: сервер, файлы, ftp, администрирование

В FileZilla файл на сервере можно открыть для редактирования. При сохранении FileZilla спрашивает, загрузить ли файл обратно на сервер. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы он загружал файл не спрашивая?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду - подправить исходные коды FileZilla, чтобы не спрашивал?

Comment: @EllaSvetlaya
Нет, я подключаюсь к своему сайту по ftp через FileZilla. FileZilla позволяет мне открыть любой файл моего сайта для редактирования. После редактирования, я сохраняю файл и FileZilla спрашивает, загрузить ли изменённый файл на сервер. Я бы хотел, чтобы он загружал изменённый файл на сервер без подтверждения.

Comment: Тогда Ваш вопрос не для SO, а скорее относится к сфере SuperUser.

Comment: Судя по тому, что данный вопрос обсуждали на форуме filezilla - функции автосохранения файлов на удаленных серверах в программе нет, причем намеренно - ради сохранности файлов пользователя. Как вариант, скачать исходные коды программы и реализовать эту функцию ;)

Comment: Под Windows приятнее работать с WinSCP - там есть то, что вам хочется. А вот что с Linux?

Comment: @EllaSvetlaya Спасибо, попробую :)

Comment: @xEdelweiss, в unix-подобных операционных системах гораздо проще устроено: монтируете отдалённую файловую систему и работаете с её файлами/каталогами как с локальными.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте настроить `FileZilla`

**Настройки** - Передачи - Действие, если если файл существует

В разделе закачки ставим "заменить файл"

Пример на картинке [image: скриншоте]

Comment: Приложите скриншот в ответ, иначе Ваш ответ потеряет актуальность, если картинку удалят на источнике. Или сделайте более расширенное описание (где-куда зайти).

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло 
http://csscolor.ru/more/screenshots/scr1.png